# Encountering error while trying to add a user to a specific project [User Entitlements - Update User Entitlemen API]

Tags: api, azure-devops

Sending a PATCH request to endpoint 
`https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/userentitlements/{userId}?api-version=5.0-preview.2`

Payload

```
[
  {
    "from": "",
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/projectEntitlements/{projId}",
    "value": {
      "id": "ms.feed"
    }
  }
]
```

Result

`"The guid specified for parameter scopeId must not be Guid.Empty.\r\nParameter name: scopeId"`

What is the proper way to add a user to a specific project? scopeId is not mentioned as a required parameter in the documentation listed below.

Thank you!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/update%20user%20entitlement?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the proper way to add a user to a specific project? scopeId is not mentioned as a required parameter in the documentation listed below.

I could not reproduce the the same error as you, but I also could not add a user to a specific project with Request body you posted.

So, I track it by tools [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler), and found the Request body as following:

```
[
  {"from":"",
    "op":0,
      "path":"/projectEntitlements",
        "value":{"projectRef":{"id":"<MyProjectID>"},"group":{"groupType":2}}

  }
]
```

Then I use this Request body and the API you posted, then I could add a user to a specific project (I am using postman):

[image]

As result, the status is 200 OK and the use is added to the project.

You can try the Request body I posted above (Replace the `<MyProjectID>`  to your specify project ID).

API Get the Projects: `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects?api-version=5.0`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, your example worked. I was unable to find a similar code snippet in the documentation which is unfortunate.